# Explain the definition of SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO and how to use it

Tags: c, winapi

```
typedef struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO
{
    ULONG ProcessId;
    BYTE ObjectTypeNumber;
    BYTE Flags;
    USHORT Handle;
    PVOID Object;
    ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
} SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO, *PSYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO;
```

I am not very experienced with C++, but from what I have learn I think this means that with this declaration whenever I declare something with the type *PSYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO what that does is that makes that something a struct of type SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO with the variables mentioned above.

I have some questions though:

1. Why make PSYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO a pointer?

   1.1. What do I get exactly when I dereference this pointer? Do I get the address of the first element of this struct? If I remember right struct elements are stored consecutively in memory, isn't it?
2. Could you give me an example of how to use this in a program? In other words, is the following correct and if not how would you do it?

`* PSYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO var;
var.ProcessId = 1234;`

3. From what I have learn't the syntax for typedef is  `typedef`   . So why is the struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO being declared and why is SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO at the end of it? And why is there a comma?

EDIT: Downvoters, could you explain? I'm open to constructive criticism.

Comment: this structure used with `NtQuerySystemInformation` `SystemHandleInformation`. however better use `SystemExtendedHandleInformation` with `SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX` - in what your problem ?

Comment: @RbMm I don't have any problem, I just want to know what that piece of code does.

Comment: but i not view any piece of code in your question

Comment: These are typedef you can use like this if you're curious about this: 
    PSYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO var = new 
    SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO;
    var->ProcessId = 1;
    std::cout << var->ProcessId;
e.g: http://cpp.sh/3jjya

Comment: @RbMm The definition of SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO right in the beginning, with the gray background

Comment: but this is standard *c* style definition of any structure (not *c++* style). faster you need mark this question as *c*

Comment: @RbMm I didn't know that, I'll change it.

Comment: look for any windows headers file. `minwinbase.h` for example - you can view that all structs here defined as `typedef struct _T {
} T, *PT;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complicated use of the `typedef` statement. We can break it down as follows.

The first part to look at, taking up most of the space, is

```
struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO
{
    ULONG ProcessId;
    BYTE ObjectTypeNumber;
    BYTE Flags;
    USHORT Handle;
    PVOID Object;
    ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
}
```

This declares a new `struct` type, named `struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO`.

In C, `struct` names and regular typenames aren’t the same; if you want to use a `struct` you always have to use the keyword `struct`.¹ However, typing this extra `struct` everywhere gets annoying, so you can `typedef` it to a regular type name. Thus we have the whole statement before the comma,

```
typedef struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO
{
    ULONG ProcessId;
    BYTE ObjectTypeNumber;
    BYTE Flags;
    USHORT Handle;
    PVOID Object;
    ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
} SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO
```

This alone would allow you to refer to the type as either `struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO` or just `SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO` from C programs, like you can either way from C++ programs.

So what’s with the last part? The `typedef` statement works like a variable declaration in a lot of ways. In particular, you can declare *multiple* typenames with a single `typedef` statement. Let’s consider a simpler example, of just a variable declaration involving the `int` type:

```
int i, *p;
```

This creates in `int` called `i`, *and* a pointer-to-`int` (`int*`) called `p`. Adding `typedef` before that would let you use `i` as a synonym for `int`, and `p` as a synonym for `int*`.

So your full statement,

```
typedef struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO
{
    ULONG ProcessId;
    BYTE ObjectTypeNumber;
    BYTE Flags;
    USHORT Handle;
    PVOID Object;
    ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
} SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO, *PSYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO;
```

does three things:

1. It creates a structure type `struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO` with the members you see named.
2. It creates a type alias `SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO` equivalent to `struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO`, allowing you to use either name in your code. This is unnecessary for C++, but necessary for C compatibility.
3. It creates a type alias `PSYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO` equivalent to `struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO*` (pointer to `struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO`), allowing you to use the name `PSYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO` whenever you want a pointer to this type of `struct`.

¹ This is removed in C++, but since C programs might also want to use the Windows API, it supports both usages.

Comment: I didn’t know until I saw your question that you could `typedef` multiple things at once like that, and I had to double-check [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef "Typedef page on cppreference") that it meant what I thought it did. I would recommend *not* writing code like this yourself.